# How to save file from c# code without change date of last write?

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I have a directory with files and my program (in C#) can change these files. If there are manual changes then I need to reload my program immediately.

I want to set a FileSystemWatcher on my directory, but I can't determine when there is a change from my program or from some other way.

I made it so that my program sets all changed files to a specific date (for example 01.01.2000) and I can see this date when the event fires in 'watcher.Changed'.

```
private static void WatcherOnChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs fileSystemEventArgs)
    {
        var currentDate = File.GetLastWriteTime(fileSystemEventArgs.FullPath);
        if (currentDate != new DateTime(2000, 1, 1))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"changed {fileSystemEventArgs.FullPath}");

        }
    }
```

The event occurs before `File.SetLastWriteTime(file, new DateTime(2000, 1, 1));`

Maybe it's bad timing? How do I fix the timing issue?

Comment: X/Y question. Why not just, say, keep track of the files your program changes and not reload the program when one of those are changed?

Comment: How I understand that it changes from my program?

Comment: I made some changes to the wording @ДенисМакушевский - please verify I didn't change your intent.

Comment: @ДенисМакушевский, if your program changes a file, you can add it to some list. Then an event is fired "file changed" and first you check that list. If the file exists on that list, remove the file from the list and do not do anything. If it does not exist there, reload the program. I hope this is clear.

Comment: I agree with AKX. Keep a dictionary of files you've edited in the last few moments. Then the filewatcher can check that dictionary and remove the entry rather than react to it.

Answer (score 3):

Elaborating on my comment:

You say your problem is that you can't determine when your `FileSystemWatcher`'s events are triggered by changes made by the user ("manual changes") or by your program.

Since you probably do control the places where your program modifies those files, you can keep track of the files it has modified in, say, a `Set<string>` of filenames, every time it modifies things.

Then, when the `OnChanged` event fires, if the filename is within that set, discard it from the set and ignore the event.

Comment: It is normal, befor async code and some exceptions. I need sure on 100%, that file change from my program or not.